# Mix animations in an 3d Tennis game

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an 3d Tennis game. This is my first Unity Game. My game requires multiple animations like running and hitting the ball, making a volley on net, Serving the ball, etc.

I am confused about how to mix multiple animations is Unity. What is the best way to approach the problem. Are blend trees appropriate to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: avatar masks and animation layers  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/avatar-masks http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I look into the Unity Video given above by you